# SQLAnywhere: How to write result of a query into a file with non-interactive session

Tags: export, sybase-sql-anywhere

I'm looking for a way to write resultset of a query to a file maybe analog of `queryout` of MS SQL or the `COPY` from PostgreSQL

When using something like

```
select count(*) from "table" OUTPUT TO 'results.txt' FORMAT TEXT
```

I'm getting

> Could not execute statement. Syntax error near 'TO' on line 1
>   SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000" Line 1, column 1

When running it, as discribed in documentation like this:

```
select count(*) from "table";
OUTPUT TO 'results.txt' FORMAT TEXT
```

e.g. inside a procedure, I'm getting an error telling me that there is no result for being outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for at least my problem. It's possible to put results into a temporary table and unload the temp table. So something like:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpresultset FROM myTable
UNLOAD TABLE #tmpresultset to '/some/file'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `OUTPUT` to a file in your SQL directly:

`dbisql -c "connection-string" SELECT * FROM table; OUTPUT TO 'results.txt' FORMAT TEXT`

As per the [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/output-statement.html).

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I was missing a `;` - try now.

Comment: This is working inside isql, but not e.g. inside non-interactive one.

Comment: Let's move this to a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19510/discussion-between-john-m-and-frlan)

Comment: In chat I've learned a lot, even we weren't able to solve my issue it helped me on the way.